# Transfering API data to a File

Tags: python, json, api, file

I am wondering how do I transfer the API data that I have, and put it into my json file. I have a json file called "GameAPI.json", and this is what I have inside of it: [image]

(What I essentially want is):
[image]

"100" represents team 1, and "200" represents team 2, and every time I load into a game of "League of Legends" the numbers inside of the teams change, and the numbers inside of those teams represents the Name of the characters inside of the game "League of Legends". So this is the code to grab the teams, and the characters inside the game:[image]

This is the raw data from when I am inside of the game, and where I got the characters and put it into my code:

```
{"gameId":4180599210,"mapId":11,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","gameQueueConfigId":420,"participants":[{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"championId":98,"profileIconId":1116,"summonerName":"TheSoupDogg","bot":false,"summonerId":"-wq2kyBhXwEfdaJ4SLNWnV5hH9topHIw9fNn2h30eGiEyiwf5eouGLrJFw","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8437,8401,8473,8451,8126,8106,5005,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8400,"perkSubStyle":8100}},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":14,"championId":157,"profileIconId":4780,"summonerName":"Edric94","bot":false,"summonerId":"E1kXZ_fF4ugeg6WipVVxaXll0USZDCS0C3dxrHfaariFWdhY","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8008,9111,9104,8299,8473,8451,5005,5008,5003],"perkStyle":8000,"perkSubStyle":8400}},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":7,"spell2Id":4,"championId":21,"profileIconId":4779,"summonerName":"thebeck","bot":false,"summonerId":"vBpd0cM1VF0flHeNv2bdarzwRBI2rUBpdiHunbXNphjMxgw","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8229,8226,8233,8237,8304,8345,5005,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8200,"perkSubStyle":8300}},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":11,"spell2Id":4,"championId":20,"profileIconId":27,"summonerName":"Turtl3zz","bot":false,"summonerId":"ur8GxpbDUcHI7bgNKIKCbWlvSflVEAf6lkSSxyE1WuCNgxL5MK6XiM-20Q","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8128,8126,8138,8105,8234,8232,5005,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8100,"perkSubStyle":8200}},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":14,"championId":412,"profileIconId":4631,"summonerName":"KITTYxD3STROY3R","bot":false,"summonerId":"Fgjnef1_R5gxExz82Nx_LKCbhlWNuieTRMX04n_wzkYk8C0","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8439,8463,8473,8242,8345,8352,5007,5002,5001],"perkStyle":8400,"perkSubStyle":8300}},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":11,"championId":32,"profileIconId":4922,"summonerName":"1OpChickenNuggs","bot":false,"summonerId":"6YSwkjQGJgeao2uqUW3ilXfLBAEhBmdoEHJ1stSLyYxCJ5k","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8010,9111,9104,8299,8126,8135,5005,5008,5003],"perkStyle":8000,"perkSubStyle":8100}},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"championId":45,"profileIconId":5030,"summonerName":"For The Father","bot":false,"summonerId":"XuLSz_AknW_CU_oPwqIKqXxFSVFgM8vDsdcd9_1Eg0DMMjv5","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8112,8139,8138,8135,8009,8014,5005,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8100,"perkSubStyle":8000}},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":14,"championId":106,"profileIconId":5212,"summonerName":"Hanisonsfriend","bot":false,"summonerId":"HFW-VKhi4RnayNCP3jTE5-1SzRUni-PzRnveiavzyX7GFe6BJq59R74MSQ","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[9923,8126,8138,8106,8210,8236,5005,5008,5001],"perkStyle":8100,"perkSubStyle":8200}},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":14,"championId":84,"profileIconId":4985,"summonerName":"SteelerFroz987","bot":false,"summonerId":"OoQECbv17KGrYZPNq97qwb7h_Ad0aHbkr0ytg3-n9px8xGc","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8010,8009,9104,8014,8126,8135,5008,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8000,"perkSubStyle":8100}},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"championId":10,"profileIconId":4378,"summonerName":"hyperionshyper","bot":false,"summonerId":"ik9boNLwEJRzFZqmkUQUQOWFe_0RADbaBjw63-APL5RlZ7A","gameCustomizationObjects":[],"perks":{"perkIds":[8008,9111,9104,8014,8473,8451,5005,5008,5002],"perkStyle":8000,"perkSubStyle":8400}}],"observers":{"encryptionKey":"LU+TrL6ssjHa8MyQlX+RxFggVyu0Wn7r"},"platformId":"NA1","bannedChampions":[{"championId":11,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":1},{"championId":34,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":2},{"championId":6,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":3},{"championId":15,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":4},{"championId":89,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":5},{"championId":39,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":6},{"championId":11,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":7},{"championId":53,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":8},{"championId":202,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":9},{"championId":90,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":10}],"gameStartTime":1642377743629,"gameLength":-113}
```

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
from collections import defaultdict
clients = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

client = httpx.Client()
URL = client.get('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v4/active-games/by-summoner/XuLSz_AknW_CU_oPwqIKqXxFSVFgM8vDsdcd9_1Eg0DMMjv5?api_key=RGAPI-9380bdea-a785-4d87-9d34-08532fc1a595').json()
#print(URL['participants'])



data = client.get("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.15.1/data/en_US/champion.json").json()
name_key = {}
for x in data['data'].values():
    name_key[int(x['key'])] = x['name']

#print(name_key)

#Championier = []
#for champions in data['data']:
#    Championier.append(int(data['data'][champions]['key']))

#print(Championier)


championIDs = {100:[], 200:[]}

for IDs in URL['participants']:
    championIDs[IDs['teamId']].append(IDs['championId'])
print(championIDs)

#team_1 = championIDs[100]

#team_2 = championIDs[200]

with open("D:\Python Code stuff I did\GameAPI.json", "r") as file:
    filedata = json.load(file)
#print(filedata)

team_1 = filedata['100']

team_2 = filedata['200']

#print(team_1)
#print(team_2)
new_team1 = []
for identifier in team_1:
    team_name1 = name_key.get(identifier)
#    print(identifier, name_key.get(identifier))
    new_team1.append(name_key.get(identifier))
    
    if team_name1 is not None:
        pass
    else:
        continue

new_team2 = []
for identifier2 in team_2:
    team_name2 = name_key.get(identifier2)
    new_team2.append(name_key.get(identifier2))

    if team_name1 is not None:
        pass
    else:
        continue



#print(new_team1)
#print(new_team2)
clients.run('-----------------')
```

Comment: to be clear, you want to put that text on the last line of the question into a file?

Comment: Yes thats what I essentially want

Comment: Ok Ill show u more of the code here

Comment: you're supposed to put your actual code in the question instead of screenshots

Comment: Ok Ill do that right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Alright check out the code I just posted it.

Comment: yeah so I dont actually get what you're doing cuz I don't use most of those libraries but consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because it seems like a lot of that code I irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

This might help [you](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) , i would open the file in "a" mode like this:

```
with open("sample.json", "a") as outfile:
    json.dump(your_json_data, outfile)
```

// insert the json data there

Comment: What json data do I have, I dont understand what you mean by json data. I grab everything from an API.

Comment: the league API returns the data in json ddgragon aswell.
Also one thing, be careful i think you posted your API key, that's against riot dev terms, you can't share it.

Comment: So you want me to get the json data from dragon.leagueoflegends? I put it into a string called "data"

Comment: If you want to put that text on the last line, you just need to do a json_dump(that_text,outfile).  If you want to form a json with the data you want i recommend using this [website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu).